# Unable to rename file

Tags: java, file, file-rename

I was trying an exercise of deleting lines from a file not starting with a particular string.
The idea was to copy the desired lines to a temp file, delete the original file and rename the temp file to original file.

My question is I am unable to rename a file!

```
tempFile.renameTo(new File(file))
```

or

```
tempFile.renameTo(inputFile)
```

do not work.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? Here is the code:

```
/**
 * The intention is to have a method which would delete (or create
 * a new file) by deleting lines starting with a particular string. *
 */
package com.dr.sort;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class RemoveLinesFromFile {

    public void removeLinesStartsWith(String file, String startsWith, Boolean keepOrigFile) {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader rd = null;
        PrintWriter wt = null;
        File tempFile = null;

        try {
            // Open input file
            File inputFile = new File(file);

            if (!inputFile.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + file + " is not a valid file.");
                return;
            }

            // Create temporary file

            tempFile = new File(file + "_OUTPUT");

            //Read input file and Write to tempFile

            rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            wt = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.substring(0, startsWith.length()).equals(startsWith)) {
                    wt.println(line);
                    wt.flush();
                }

            }
            rd.close();

            if (!keepOrigFile) {

                inputFile.delete();

                if (tempFile.renameTo(new File(file))) {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NOT OK");
                }
            }

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (tempFile != null && tempFile.isFile()) {
                wt.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what error you're getting, or what exactly your question is.

Comment: Sorry all. My question is  I am unable to rename file. tempFile.renameTo(new File(file)) or tempFile.renameTo(inputFile) does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you need to close your PrintWriter *before* renaming.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (line.substring(0, startsWith.length()).equals(startsWith))
```

should instead be the opposite, because we don't want the lines that are specified to be included.
so:

```
if (!line.substring(0, startsWith.length()).equals(startsWith))
```